# Ruby gem for ADB protocol?

Tags: android, ruby, adb

A coworker of mine believes that there is a Ruby gem out there that implements an ADB client in Ruby - thus allowing Ruby code to work with ADB in an OO manner rather than just driving the command-line client via shell. He doesn't know what this gem is, but he feels very sure that he's seen it.

After searching search engines every which way I can think of, I'm not so sure he's that sure. :-) I can't find anything like this. Does this sound familiar to anyone? If it's a simple protocol that goes through a TCP port, it seems like it'd be a no-brainer to implement using Net::Telnet or something. I would, but I can't find a specification of this protocol anywhere, and of course I don't want to reinvent the wheel if this has already been done.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no specification. There are various JARs in the tools that implement the client side of the ADB protocol. I used those to create DroidEx back in the day, which later morphed into [Jens Riboe's Droid@Screen](http://blog.ribomation.com/droid-at-screen/). In principle, those JARs could be used by JRuby, though I haven't tried it. I don't recall seeing an ADB client as a native Ruby gem, though.

Comment: In an ideal world, I would be able to use JRuby, but other factors beyond my control forbid me from taking that more sensible path. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the ruby gem "android-adb".  Will this work for you?

https://rubygems.org/gems/android-adb

Comment: This fits as a comment to the question. Have you tried it and testes? Does it really work and you feel that it's answering the problem OP is having?